# How to Enable/Disable system soft Navigation keys on pressing switch Button?

Tags: android, android-source, android-7.1-nougat

I have a case where i need to use soft navigation keys instead of Hardware navigation keys on a switch button.

I am using system property

```
Settings.Secure.SYSTEM_NAVIGATION_KEYS_ENABLED
```

w.r.to this i want to disable/enable soft navigation keys for complete Android System.

Just like in **Oneplus Phone**, i need to provide switch button to enable and disable soft navigation bar.

Does anyone help how to achieve this.

Comment: you need to create custom system overlay layout for providing navigatio